# Spinner pop up window title background

Tags: android, styles, spinner

I would like to modify the background of the title bar of the dropdown dialog associated to a spinner.

If this is not possible I would like to know what resource is used to draw this background android.R.drawable.* ?

This is an effort of uniformity for my various pop ups in my application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change everything using styles and themes.
Take a look at this example for buttons:
http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/

Comment: i know about styles and themes but it does not tell me how to access the properties of the window that is being popped up when I click on my spinner. thanks anyways !